# Passing only value for private members

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I am creating a class with one array as its private member and getter,setter method for that. I want set a value to that array using an array in main function. When I manipulate the array in main function, it should not affect the array present in that class.

I tried this code, but here the array is manipulated

```
class ClassB {

    private int[] a;

    ClassB() { }

    ClassB(int[] a) {
        this.a=a;
    }

    int[] geta() {
        return this.a;
    }

    void seta(int a[]) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class ClassA{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] d = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter array elements : ");
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
            d[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        final ClassB cb2 = new ClassB(d);
        d[3] = 15;
        System.out.println("After changing array d : \n Values of array d :");
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
            System.out.println(d[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Values of array a of cb2 :");
        int[] b = cb2.geta();
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect :

```
Enter size :

5

Enter array elements :
1
2
3
4
5
After changing array d :

 Values of array d :

1
2
3
15
5

Values of array a of cb2 :
1
2
3
4
5
```

But the actual output was :

```
Enter size :

5

Enter array elements :

1
2
3
4
5

After changing array d :

 Values of array d :

1
2
3
15
5

Values of array a of cb2 :

1
2
3
15
5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a mutable object to an immutable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213798/convert-a-mutable-object-to-an-immutable-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make *defensive copies* in `ClassB` every time you set the array or need to return its values. Like this:

```
class ClassB {
    // ... code omitted for brevity

    ClassB(int[] a) {
        seta(a);
    }

    int[] geta() {
        int[] copy = new int[a.length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, copy, 0, a.length);
        return copy;
    }

    void seta(int a[]) {
        this.a = new int[a.length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, this.a, 0, a.length);
    }
}
```

*Side notes*:

- If you really want to make `ClassB` immutable, you shouldn't have a setter for its values.
- The utility [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) was used to create a copy of the arrays. Feel free to use here whatever fits better your needs (you may want to consider using `a.clone()`... this is a good topic about it: [Why clone() is the best way for copying arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145826/why-clone-is-the-best-way-for-copying-arrays)).

*Additional readings:*

- [Copy constructors and defensive copying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15020850/5640649)
- [How do I make defensive copy of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2954791/5640649)
- [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/5640649).
- [Clone method for Java arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14149733/5640649)

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing `final ClassB cb2 = new ClassB(d);`, you are essentially passing the *reference* of the array *b* to `ClassB`. Since both the references are same, the array inside `ClassB` is changing.

Must read - [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/820410)

You will have to make a copy of the array, if you want the changes done to `d` not affect the array inside `ClassB`. Change your constructor to the following:

```
ClassB(int[] a) {
    this.a = a.clone();
}
```

---

**Note:**

Also, making `ClassB` object final (`final ClassB cb2`) makes its object `cb2` as immutable. Not the objects inside it.

Hence, you cannot change `cb2` but can definitely change `cb2.a`, when you do the following :

```
final ClassB cb2 = new ClassB(d);
```